# C++ STL Comparison class: how to parameterize comp-class behaviour?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, c++11, priority-queue

i want to use a std::priority_queue container with a custom data-type and several comparison-criterions (i defined a functor for each of them; each of them are working on the same types).
The comparison criterion itself used should be configurable through a function parameter (avoiding if_then_ initializations of the queue).

Based on [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/259010184a91c7a7), which is, as far as i understand it, using a comparison functor, which itself is initialized with a function pointer to one of the defined comparison functions, i tried to use a configurable comparison functor, which is initialized with another comparison functor (which is then stored locally and used when called). I did not get it to work yet.

I don't even know if it is possible to do what i want in general. I don't know if i did something wrong regarding the types (i used typedef boost::function xxx) or need additional C++0x features (would "closures" help?).

So basically i want to have something like the following to be working (this won't compile with an non-long but ugly error; GCC 4.5):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

typedef boost::tuple<double, int> custom_type;  // example only!
typedef boost::function<bool (const custom_type & l, const custom_type & r)> comp_type; // comparison functor

struct fifo_comp
{
    bool operator() (const custom_type & l, const custom_type & r) const
    {
        // compare only id
        return l.get<1>() > r.get<1>();
    }
};

struct lifo_comp
{
    bool operator() (const custom_type & l, const custom_type & r)
    {
        // compare only id
        return l.get<1>() < r.get<1>();
    }
};

class Compare
{
    public:
        explicit Compare(const comp_type & comp);

        bool operator() (const custom_type & l, const custom_type & r)
        {
            return comp(l, r);
        }

    private:
        const comp_type & comp;
};

class Some_Class_Using_Queue
{
public:
    Some_Class_Using_Queue(comp_type & comp) : pqueue(Compare(comp)) {}

    void test()
    {
        pqueue.push(custom_type(1.0, 1));
    }

private:
    std::priority_queue<custom_type, std::vector<custom_type>, Compare> pqueue;
};

int main()
{
    comp_type f = fifo_comp();
    Some_Class_Using_Queue temp((f));    // critical
    temp.test();
    return 1;
}
```

- **Any help to get it to work for me (use of STL/Boost is encouraged)?**
- **Any better ideas (do it completely different)?**
- **Are there any cool C++0x features helping here (maybe closures)?**

Thank you.

*PS/Edit: I know, that it is possible and really easy to make the class templated and call the class with the appropriate comp-class as template-param. But i don't know if that's a better way to do it (regarding design). With this approach i would have to switch/if-else before calling because of the need of the template param to be available at compile-time.*

PS: I setthe "priority_queue" tag, even if the question is maybe completely independent on this adaptor-class. If someone wants to remove it, just do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the definition of `Compare`'s constructor:

```
explicit Compare(const comp_type & comp) : comp(comp) { }
```

Other than that, it builds and runs for me.

Also, `Compare` appears to be redundant. It just wraps comp_type with an identical interface. The code still builds and runs after removing the `Compare` class and replacing it with `comp_type` everywhere.

Comment: Okay, that was easy. Compiling now. Thanks for your really quick answer.

Comment: The `explicit` keyword merely indicates that it cannot be invoked implicitly when a conversion is required. You still need to provide a definition. Your existing code is valid, but it only *declares* the constructor; it doesn't define it. Thus, the error I was seeing was a missing symbol (the constructor) at the link stage, not a compiler error.

Comment: Yes, i misread your answer and edited my comment too late. But thanks again for your clarification. Everything is working now.

Comment: And thanks again for your additional "redundancy" hint. I think i was in someway affected by my posted link and wanted to translate it 1:1 to functors.